# Kivy Look and Feel

Tags: python, kivy

I am trying to build a Kivy application with a sharp, crisp look and feel but the default Kivy UI is not exactly what I had in mind? Is there any way to create a custom theme to give your Kivy app style?

[image]

This app here is called Pithon and it was made from Kivy. I have searched everywhere but I can not find anything on how the developer managed such a clean look. Does anyone have any ideas?

[image]

Comment: I am really desperate for some help regarding this issue? Stack Overflow isn't all about reputation and procedure. Please overlook the broad question and help me to solve this issue.

Comment: those are just labelWidgets with a light grey background ... and likely a png circle with text overlaid. theres lots of tutorials on specifying fonts .... im not sure what your question really is ...  https://github.com/kivy/kivy/wiki/Theming-Kivy this link might be of immediate interest to you however

Comment: Unfortunately such questions always get slammed in SO.

Comment: So if it is a label how did the developer specify the fixed padding?

Comment: so maybe he used buttons which iirc have color attributes and font attributes as well...

Answer (score 16):

A kivy developer called Andrés Rodríguez released a set of widgets based on google's material design principles. I am currently using them myself and they have surely saved me from alot of work. You can find [KivyMD here](https://gitlab.com/kivymd/KivyMD) (see bottom of this answer for more info). Their are some themes also based on the same principles but am yet to try them out one is [FlatKivy](https://github.com/Kovak/FlatKivy) and another is kivy material ui by Federico Curzel.

Some screenshots for kivyMD,flatkivy and kivy material ui respectively  are here.
[image: KivyMD]

[image: FlatKivy]

[image: kivy material UI]

Click the highlighted links you will find a lot more info about the three projects.

---

> The [original](https://gitlab.com/kivymd/KivyMD) **KivyMD** project by Andrés Rodríguez is no longer maintained but there is active [fork of **KivyMD**](https://github.com/HeaTTheatR/KivyMD) by [HeaTTheatR](https://github.com/HeaTTheatR).

Comment: Could you add a how to use or demo screenshots to your answer?

Comment: @spacemonkey most of these are somewhat new projects and the documentation isn't mature. The author of kivyMD said he would release documentation for his project in the not so distant future, so lets just keep our fingers crossed.

Comment: @TumukundeArnold Sorry about that. That wasn't a productive comment. The projects look really good. Looking forward to following them as they mature.

Comment: Did you simply overwrite the default theme of kivy? Or how do you use kivy themes? I can't find a solution to this anywhere!

Answer (score 4):

(Almost) all widgets have properties that can be used to set aspects of their style. For instance, with a Button you can change the background colour, the background image when pressed or released, and the size of the border region (it's scaled like in CSS border images). You can check the documentation for the specifics of a given widget.

An theme like in the screenshot you posted could be achieved by turning off background images for the buttons and just using solid colours, with the non-button text being normal Labels and the circle being drawn directly with a kivy canvas instruction or via an Image widget (along with an image of the circle).

I notice you mentioned padding in a comment but I'm not sure what you mean by it - do you mean the distance between the buttons? They may well be placed in a GridLayout which has a padding property controlling this, so you could set it to whatever you like.

I recognise that you're asking a more general question than 'how does this screenshot do it?', but the key point is that just about everything is customisable and it doesn't take many changes to go from the default theme to your image.

Edit: One useful feature that helps this kind of customisation is that you can use kv language to override styles for widget classes very easily, so you don't need to manually change every button etc.

Comment: Yes I understand that much but I am having issues. For example, when I try to supply a background color for my button I get white instead of the RGBA gray `(227, 227, 227, 1)`.

Comment: In my experience the RGBA numbers range from 0 to 1, so instead of `(227, 227, 227, 1)` you should have `(227/255, 227/255, 227/255, 1)`

Comment: That's correct, kivy follows the opengl conventions for this kind of thing.

Comment: Although also note that if you use python2 without `from __future__ import division` then `227/255` will evaluate to 0. `227/255.0` will always work though (or other ways of ensuring float division).