# how to put windows theme buttons and widgets on the kivy layouts

Tags: python, user-interface, kivy

I intent to produce an application for windows OS and want its GUI to be designed in python kivy.

> the problem is when some widget like Button is added to the layout, i got the button without windows OS themes applied. i need the button and the entire GUI widgets with operating system themes. what i have to do?

here is a simple code of GUI with a button on it. manipulation required?:

```
from kivy.app import App
from kivy.uix.button import Button
from kivy.uix.floatlayout import FloatLayout
class TestApp(App):
    def build(self):
        layout = FloatLayout(orientation='vertical')
        btn =  Button(text='The button!',size_hint=(0.2,0.1),pos=(200,200))        
        layout.add_widget(btn)
        return layout
    def callback(self, event):
        print("button touched")
        self.label.text = "button touched"
if __name__ == "__main__":
    TestApp().run()
```

Comment: What do you mean by "windows themes"? Do you want the operating system theme to be used? Kivy does not use native gui widgets ...

Comment: yes. i mean OS themes. No way?

Comment: No. You can however create/use custom themes if you don't like the original. Check out https://github.com/kivy/kivy/wiki/Theming-Kivy and https://stackoverflow.com/questions/29928496/kivy-look-and-feel

Comment: Maybe you need to do this with tkinter, if you need it to be the same theme as windows.

Comment: I want to run the app on android as well. That's why i chose kivy, otherwise i would have selected pyQT or tkinter. Tnx anyway

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As stated by others in comments, it's not how kivy works, ease of porting of every platforms and ability to build custom widgets comes at the cost of system integration, kivy widgets look the same whatever the platform, and doesn't feel native anywhere, unless you spend time making them do. You can define rules for your widgets specific to each platforms, to make them look and feel native, but it's work, and if you want it to follow user theming, then it's certainly out of reach for any reasonable effort, with kivy it's you who decides how your application look, not the system.